# Javascript: Dictionary 'key' value becomes null outside for loop

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I have a function which takes a list of dictionaries `[{}]` as an argument. It manipulates this list of dicts by adding a new `key: value` pair to it where value is again a list of dictionaries. This is what the function looks like, I've added comments to explain it.

```
function addFilesToProjects(nonUniqueArray, lists) {
    var fileList = [{}]; //this will contain the list of dictionaries that I want to add as a key to the array 'nonUniqueArray'
    var filesArray = []; //this was just for testing purposes because I want to access the modified version of nonUniqueArray outside the function, which I'm not able to (it shows undefined for the new key:value pair)
    for (var i = 0; i < nonUniqueArray.length; i++) {
        lists.forEach(function (list) {
            fileNameString = JSON.stringify(list['name']).slice(2, -2);
            if (fileNameString.indexOf(nonUniqueArray[i]['title']) !== -1 && fileNameString !== nonUniqueArray[i]['title']) {
                fileList.push({
                    'name': fileNameString
                });
            }
        });
        nonUniqueArray[i]['files'] = fileList;

        //this logs out the right key:value pair to the console
        console.log(nonUniqueArray[i]);

        filesArray.push(nonUniqueArray[i]);
        while (fileList.length > 0) {
            fileList.pop();
        }
    }

    //however, now I get everything as before except the new 'files' key has empty list [] as its value :( 
    console.log(nonUniqueArray);

    return filesArray;
}
```

I have no clue why is this happening, can someone help?

Comment: Step through the code with the fully-featured debugger built into your IDE or browser. That's the best way to know what's happening and what's going wrong.

Comment: `now I get everything as before except the new 'files' key has empty list` well, don't you empty it not even five lines above?

Comment: I'm popping everything out of the filesArray array, not the nonUniqueArray. Also, this is on the server side and I'm coding on sublime. I'm debugging using console.logs but it's not helping me

Comment: Actually...I'm not so sure any more. This is a really confusing piece of code to look at there are three loops that manipulate three arrays and then some of the arrays are derived from other of the arrays.

Comment: please add the call of the function as well with some data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to think that you are adding a *copy* of `fileList` into each dictionary, but in fact are adding the *same* `fileList` into each (that is, each is a reference to the same object) so that, as @vlaz points out, when you empty out the original, you are in fact emptying out what appears in each dictionary.

Comment: OK, that gives me some reassurance - that's what I thought happened at first, but then when I tried to trace it back through the code, I got confused.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. What's the workaround for this? After every iteration I have to make the list empty otherwise it'll add what it currently has + the data it acquires in the next iteration.

Comment: @user3728233 the "workaround" is to take copy of the array calling `arr.slice(0)`. The proper solution would be to re-write that function as I'm still reading it and I still have no idea what it's doing aside from moving stuff from a bunch of arrays. It seems unnecessarily complex.